# Total column in matrix table

Tags: sql, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I need to add to matrix report column called "total" that will sum values from number fields as shown on the picture:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If u use simple SubTotal (righ-click on column group and use SubTotal) and if u have more than 1 column in group, it will make subtotal column for each column in group (in your case, it will make 2 columns). I asume, this is not what u want.

U can add statitc row group (just use 1=1 as expression for grouping) and simple =SUM(Fields!Amount.Value) as expression for cell. There is one bad thing in this method: column will not be on the end of all columns. 
If u ever want to use SubTotal function, check this link: http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jorg_klein/archive/2007/12/06/ssrs-custom-expressions-for-subtotals-in-a-matrix.aspx. Using this method u will be able write your own agregate functions (ex. AVG) not only SUM. U can even use it to change layout of cells, row subtotal cells, column subtotal cells and entire matrix subtotal (ex: diffrent colors for every second row)

I don't have enough rep points to paste pictures or examples - i can send the to u by @

PS: My english is not good, i know :) Working on it...

Comment: Right, but if I create subtotal it will also generete total for % column.

I want only to sum number values (check the picture)

http://i.imgur.com/DgkT4Q8.png